SwiftUI segmented Picker not truncating Labels or sizing, macOS
I have a simple SwiftUI Picker, that hardly resists sizing correctly.
The picker should simply stick to the .frame(width: xx) modifier, but it breaches it always as if it's in the background with something like .ignoresSafeArea set.

Application is for macOS 14 (Sonoma)


Things i have tried in almost all combinations:

.fixedSize()
.truncationMode()
.frame() // on the Picker and/or on the Text
layoutPriority()

How to make the Picker stay in its containing Window?
import SwiftUI

struct DummyPicker: View {
    
    @State var selected: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
            Picker(selection: $selected, label: EmptyView()) {
                Text("1 Text should truncate")
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .truncationMode(.tail)
                    .frame(width: 40)
                    .fixedSize()
                
                Text("2 Text should truncate")
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .truncationMode(.tail)
                    .frame(width: 40)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .truncationMode(.tail)
            .layoutPriority(2)
            
    }
}

#Preview {
    Group {
        DummyPicker()
            .frame(width: 200)
            .padding()
    }
}



It looks like the native implementation always uses a line limit of 1 and never truncates. You cannot change this, nor can you do much to change the styling of a segmented picker. If you want a picker that looks or behaves differently then your best bet is probably to create your own custom segmented picker, which is not very difficult. You can then style it any way you like, including line wrapping instead of truncation if you wanted to. For moving a shape behind the selection, .matchedGeometryEffect can be used, see this answer for an example.
